# C # Two-dimensional int array,Sum off all elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I tried to make a program which sums the elements in an array. But I have '**System.IndexOutOfRangeException**' mistake on MVS. Can somebody tell where is my mistake?

```
public static int Sum(int[,] arr)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= arr.Length; j++)
        {
            total += arr[i,j];
        }
    }
    return total;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] arr = { { 1, 3 }, { 0, -11 } };
    int total = Sum(arr);

    Console.WriteLine(total);
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get the length of each dimension (the `Length` property of a 2D array is the total number of items in the array) and the comparison should be `<`, not `<=`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
         total += arr[i,j];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach (int item in arr)
{
    total += item;
}
```

Or even Linq

```
int total = arr.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try *Linq*

```
  int[,] arr = { { 1, 3 }, { 0, -11 } };

  int total = arr.OfType<int>().Sum();
```

Non Linq solution:

```
  int total = 0;

  foreach (var item in arr)
    total += item;
```

Comment: or `Cast<int>().Sum()`. No need to check the type

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your loops are checking for <= and they should be < 
As they are zero index arrays, checking for <= arr.Length will always result in an index out of range exception.

Comment: That's only half the problem. In this case `Length` is 4, not 2.  You have to use `GetLength` to get the length of each dimension.