# Summing a jagged int array in C#

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

As done here: [C # Two-dimensional int array,Sum off all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267553/c-two-dimensional-int-array-sum-off-all-elements), but this time with jagged arrays. Getting:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

I am a beginner asking for help. This is my code:

```
public static int Sum(int[][] arr) 
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++) 
         { 
              total += arr[i][j];
         }
    } 
    return total; 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int[][] arr = new int[][] 
     {
          new int [] {1},
          new int [] {1,3,-5},
     };
     int total = Sum(arr);
     Console.WriteLine();
     Console.ReadKey();    
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with the convention rules. For example use Ctrk+K+D in Visual Studio. It`s really unpleasantly to read your code). Read more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: @GiladGreen - Thank you for your answer.Programme is working.But output shows empty space

Comment: @Shopska - you need to add the total to the `WriteLine`

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks for your kindly message haha.May i ask to you that,what kind of difference makes from "khlr" answer,when i add;   ' if (arr[i] != null) '? Could you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a jagged array the dimensions of that array aren't necessarily even. Have a look at the initialization code of that jagged array:

```
int[][] arr = new int[][] {
    new int [] {1},
    new int [] {1,3,-5},
};
```

So in the first dimension, there are two elements (`{1}` and `{1, 3, -5}`). But the second dimension isn't of the same length. The first element has got only one element (`{1}`) whereas the second element's got 3 elements (`{1, 3, -5}`).
That's why you're facing the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

To fix that, you'll have to adjust the inner loop to the number of elements for that dimension. You can do that like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++) { 
        total += arr[i][j];
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what exactly didn't work? When I run the code, it works. Although you should additionally watch for `NULL`s as @Gilad pointed out already.

Comment: sorry,its my mistake which "Gilad Green" explained it :)

Answer (score 3):

In your inner loop do this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++) 
        { 
            total += arr[i][j];
        }  
    }
} 
return total;
```

Because your lists aren't even you get the exception on `arr.GetLength(1)` for the first dimension - it has no item at that place.

The `if (arr[i] != null)` line is needed in the case the array would look something like:

```
 int[][] arr = new int[][] 
 {
      new int [] {1},
      null,
      new int [] {1,3,-5},
 };
```

In this case, when we loop with `i==1` and try to do `arr[i].Length` (meaning `arr[1].Length` we will recieve a `NullReferenceException`.

---

And after you do the basics and get to Linq all your current `Sum` method can be replaced with:

```
arr.SelectMany(item => item).Sum()
```

But it is good to start with the basics :)

Comment: `SelectMany` is smart. Without it one could do `arr.Sum(item => item.Sum())`. Neither of your solutions will work in the case where some of the "inner" arrays are `null`.

Comment: fixed the `null` case

Comment: @Shopska - Added explanation about the `null`.